# How to paginate results returned from eloquent's with() method

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am on Laravel 8. I am loading results with an intermediate table and am looping through and displaying the results. I have a lot of results coming back... how do I paginate in laravel with eloquents with() and get() methods.

If I have something like this (from docs)

```
$users = User::with('podcasts')->get();
```

It doesn't work if I do this:

```
$users = User::with('podcasts')->get()->paginate(15);

Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.
```

or

```
$users = User::with('podcasts')::paginate(15)->get(),
```

If I do this, it brings back the correct results but there are no pagination buttons/controls so I only see the first 15 results (or whatever number I specify in paginate())

```
$users = User::with('podcasts')->paginate(15)->all();
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do `Podcast::paginate(15)`? Why do you need to query `User`? Right now, you're paginating so you see 15 Users, with unlimited podcasts, but if you query the `Podcast` model directly, then you're see 15 Podcasts.

Comment: @TimLewis I am primarily querying users and then also need the results from the relationship between users and the podcasts they are subscribed to. When outputting on the front end, I need to match the PK and FK from users table to podcasts tables so each users profile outputs the podcast they specifically subscribe to and not ALL podcasts

Comment: @TimLewis it gets too messy to pass both full collections from the controller to the front end and then try to do the id matching logic there instead of just letting laravel handle the relationship matching for me.

Comment: I understand that. The catch is that `paginate()` works on a single result set, not nested ones (i.e. User > Podcasts). Additionally, since each user can have infinite `podcasts`, even if you did `User::with('podcasts')->first()`, and tried to display that User and the Podcasts, you might still end up with too many records. I'm not sure how you want to approach this, but the short answer is pagination isn't going to work for what you're trying to do (at least not the build in pagination; there might be something out there that does this, but I haven't seen anything)

Comment: You don't need to use `get()` if you use `paginate()` so your code will be : `$users = User::with('podcasts')->paginate(15);`

Comment: @TimLewis thanks for the feedback, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: As @sta wrote the last line should work if you remove "->all()" after paginate()